# Laravel Eloquent join table and count related

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, categories and product. I'm trying to add a query to count products of each category without foreach of the categories. I reached the query below:

```
DB::table('categories')->leftJoin('product', 'categories.id', '=','categpry_id')
->selectRaw('categories.*, count(product.id) as Count')
->where('product.status',1)
->groupBy('categories.id')
->get();
```

But the problem I'm facing is when a category doesn't have products it's not showing. I want to show the categories with no product with 0 product in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eloquent's `withCount` method:

```
$categories = Category::withCount('products')->get();
```

Each `$category` will have a `products_count` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use `rightJoin` for this.

Not 100% sure though.

Comment: No it was because of the where clause i did not noticed that is not mentioned in the issue

Answer (score 0):

#### The first line in your code is bad in a few ways

`'categories.id', '=','categpry_id')`

1. You have a typo
2. Add the table also `'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id'`

If you're using models, which you should be... @DigitalDrifter has an "Eloquent" solution.

#### Two asides

1. I would refrain from using mysql reserved words in your aliases. `COUNT(product.id) AS product_count` instead.
2. You can minimize your raw statement with an array passed to `select` instead.

#### Here is what I would use

```
Categories::leftJoin(Product::class, 'product.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->select([
        'categories.*',
        DB::raw('COUNT(products.id) AS product_count')
    ])
    ->where('product.status', 1)
    ->groupBy('categories.id')
    ->get();
```

#### TIL.

`Model::withCount('relation')` that is pretty darn cool too.